# Erro: Content-Length and stream length disagree

Tags: java, android, retrofit

Se usar um `Log` desta forma resgatando o corpo do *response*:

```
Log.wtf(TAG,""+response.body().string());
```

Imprime corretamente o valor do JSON. Algo nesse formato:

```
{"error":true,"message":"Login failed. Incorrect credentials"}
```

Porém se eu inserir o objeto do `response.body().string()` em um `JSONObject` desta forma:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.body().string());
```

Dá o seguinte erro:

> java.io.IOException: Content-Length and stream length disagree

O que pode estar acontecendo?